# Take screenshot of Unity scene in Android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity scene as a part of a view in my Android app. This is how I set it after exporting the project from Unity editor.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main);

    mUnityPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    binding.scene.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(), 0, lp);
}
```

This works fine. Now I need to take the screenshot of this scene and show it in another `ImageView`. The problem is that UnityPlayer is a `FrameLayout` and I expected to use `getDrawingCache()` on that to get the screenshot.

But that only returns me my background image `R.drawable.some_drawable` and any text and other info in the Unity scene isn't present in the screenshot. I think this is happening probably because the other contents aren't part of a FrameLayout and are rendered on some `TextureView` or something. I may be completely wrong. But I can't figure out how to get a screenshot of the contents inside the scene as a `Bitmap` that I can set on another `imageView`.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some images.

Comment: You can make a screen shot from Unity player (ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot) and use that one.